# don't see the slider

Tags: magento2, slider

I noticed that I cannot see anymore my pictures of my slider on my website https://agoshop.at/algenentferner/ only the points.
I use the slider SLAVA YURTHEV.
Here my code:

```
<p>{{widget type="SY\Slider\Block\Widget" ids="3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21"}}</p>
```

When I press F12 I will see the slider.

Also I noticed is, that I cannot acitvate the Page Cache and WeltPixel GoogleTagManager Categories Cache. But I don't know if this has a connection with the slider.

Hope someone can help me there.
kindly regards

Comment: Hello,
Can you please contact on live:tusharlathiya1996,
I'll help you to resolve this things.

Answer (score 0):

I will help you to solve it out your issue. Please connect me over the skype : bliss.ram786 so i will assist you for the quick solution.